# how can bind array values in map function react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mern, map-function

hope you are doing great, I am trying to bind array values in my map function but I am unsuccessful in achieving my result

Here is the console result of  line number 32 where I am getting data
[image]

here is my code
[image]

my screen is looking like this now
[image]

[image]

if i {console.log(item)} inside the map function

Comment: looks like each item is an array of 1 element. so use `item[0].name` ?. but since 0th item is an empty array so `item[0]?.name`

Comment: Can you offer us code snippets instead so we can start digging into it?

Comment: it is coming because i initialize state by empty array   ```const [fdata, setFdata] = useState([]);``` because if i am not doing this so it giving me error  ```OrderList.jsx:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fdata is not iterable```

Comment: Don't post code as images, take the time to type it out and even better provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are having your object inside an array, so whenever you are mapping the fdata array then inside that there is another array so instead of using, item.name, item.sellingPrice use item[0].name, itme[0].sellingPrice

Comment: so how can i map it

Comment: You just have to place [0] besides your item with optional chaining like itme[0]?.name, item[0]?.sellingPrice, this will automatically fetch the data from your object.

Comment: i tried but it is not working

Comment: can you share the codesandbox link with your code?

Comment: i never upload code sandbox so i am not sure how to upload mern application on that

Comment: okay, can you just console the item inside the map and share with me what is getting printed in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243762/discussion-between-zaryab-khan-and-smith-chokshi).

Comment: kindly check the question again i updated

Comment: @ZaryabKhan
https://codesandbox.io/s/new?utm_source=dotnew
That's a fresh new react sandbox. Write some code to reproduce that issue.